# Copy a std::set efficiently

Tags: c++, set

In my application, I have a module that manages some sorted sets representing part of the application's current state. They are stored in a 2d fixed-size array (i.e. `std::array<std::array<std::set<MyObj, MyObjCmp>, x>, y>`).

Another module uses these sets as a starting point for a simulation of how the state is expected to change over the next few minutes. During the simulation, it needs to modify the data stored in the sets. As the simulation module should not change the first module's current state, I am taking a copy of the sets before running the simulation. I'm doing the copy through simple assignment.

In profiling my simulator, I am seeing that the copying is much more expensive than I had expected. In the call stack of `std::array::operator=`, I am seeing calls to my set comparator function, which seems to indicate that the set copy is actually inserting all of the elements again rather than copying them directly in their current sorted order.

Is there any way to copy a `std::set` in a more efficient way?

Comment: operator= for a set is guaranteed to have linear complexity, as is the copy constructor. You cannot get more efficient than that.

Comment: Does your client really need a set? Or only the values? If so copy to a simpler datastructure and return that to the caller.

Comment: @john - scaling as O(_n_) says nothing about the constant factor.  That said, you should expect your standard library's `operator=()` to be as efficient as reasonably possible - and if not, then make it so and submit a patch!

Comment: *copying them directly in their current sorted order* Doesn't look trivial. How would a node get copied? It will have left and right children, which will in turn have left and right children and so on. If the nodes have deep copy constructor implemented, only then maybe insert (and calling comparators) can be avoided.

Comment: Probably you are seeing calls to `insert` with a hint. That is amortized constant time as long as the hint is correct (which it will be in the case of sorted insertions into an empty set). But you need to use your debugger and experiment.

Comment: depends on your standard library's implementation: https://godbolt.org/z/G61rjKfcj which one are you using?

Comment: Do you have C++23? `std::flat_set` seems to be able to copy without checking the elements are in order, going by how it's `replace` is specified

Answer (score 1):

Caleth's comment pointing at `flat_set` looks like the way to go for efficient copying while preserving set semantics. I'm on C++20 though so I haven't been able to test this directly.

I was able to take that inspiration and refactor my code to use `std::vector` as the container, with manual calls to `std::sort` as needed. Profiling shows that for my use case the copy is 10x faster and all other usages are roughly the same.